# symfony : Problem with the method 'embedRelation'

Tags: symfony1, foreign-keys, nested-forms

I have two classes with a relation one-to-many. And I want to make a nested form to enter an object and some of others which are linked to it.

But when I save the form, the key wich references my main class isn't update with the key of main class. However the other keys are created.

My schema :

```
Enfant:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: enfant
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nudparent:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Locataire:
      local: nudparent
      foreign: nud
      type: one
Locataire:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: locataire
  columns:
    nud:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    nbenfants:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Bail:
      local: nud
      foreign: locataire
      type: many
    Enfant:
      local: nud
      foreign: nudparent
      type: many
    Refus:
      local: nud
      foreign: nud
      type: many
```

And making form :

```
$subForm = new sfForm();
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
    $enfant = new Enfant();
    $enfant->Locataire = $this->getObject();

    $form = new EnfantForm($enfant);

    $subForm->embedForm($i, $form);
 }
 $this->embedForm('new', $subForm);
```

Comment: Could you post the Locataire schema please.

Comment: +1, I have the same problem with many forms, and I have to do something like "parent->setChild($child);" and save the parent again to get it to work. I think this automatic save works if the child references the parent but not the other way round.

Comment: @johnwards : I have already post the Locataire schema, I don't see what you want...

@gregOire : In tutorials, I have seen we can do this, but when I do the same thing, it doesn't work

Comment: @gregOire : Can you explain me your method to save nested forms please ?

Comment: I did not know one could initialize a form with an object, so now it works for me... Here is what I did before: (a library has an information_id column):
        $library = $this->form->save();
        /* @var $library libraryForm */
        $library->setInformation(
          $this->form->getEmbeddedForm('Library')->getObject());
        $library->save();
Tell me if this works for you

Comment: I don't know how I have down it but now, it works. But I have modify nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use embedRelation. You can find more information and examples here: http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/2009/11/29/Embedding-Relations-in-Forms-with-Symfony-1.3-and-Doctrine